# From GUID of WlanEnumInterfaces to hardware id, driver version etc

Tags: windows, msdn, wlanapi

I am currently using the windows native wifi functions for some stuff. This is a really
good abstraction and easy to use for me.

Now i need some more details on the wifi interfaces i get with [WlanEnumInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706716%28v=vs.8.5%29.aspx).

Basically i want the information available in the hardware manager, like hardware id, driver version etc.

I don't now how to get from GUID to some lower level identification of the devices and i even
do not now which methods are available to query detailed device information.

Looking forward for some help.

Philipp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok easiest way for me is to query the registry:

```
SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Class\\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
```

Where {4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318} is the class guid for network adapters.
Then i can parse for my GUID in NetCfgInstanceId.

Regards

Comment: Nice, thanks for posting your own answer. I was wondering how to do this!